# Probabilmente + indicativo o congiuntivo?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subjunctive-mood

So che il congiuntivo si usa dopo espressioni che indicano dubbio o incertezza, e ho letto alcune frasi con la struttura

> "è probabile che" + congiuntivo.

Ad esempio:

> È probabile che arrivi (o che sia arrivato) prima di me (fonte: [Treccani.it](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/probabile/)).

Il mio dubbio è: se si scrive l'avverbio "probabilmente" al posto dell'espressione "è probabile che", si deve usare il congiuntivo o l'indicativo? Per esempio, quali sono le forme corrette?

- Probabilmente arrivi prima di me.
- Probabilmente arriverà prima di me.
- Probabilmente sia arrivato prima di me.
- Probabilmente è arrivato prima di me.
- Probabilmente si possano trovare soluzioni più interessanti.
- Probabilmente si possono trovare soluzioni più interessanti.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il succo è che non è il solo fatto di esprimere un'azione possibile o eventuale a richiedere il congiuntivo; è il fatto che questa azione sia espressa in una *subordinata*. È rarissimo che in una proposizione principale il verbo sia al congiuntivo.  Quindi “È probabile che io arrivi” ma “Probabilmente arrivo/arriverò” e così via.

Comment: "Fusse che fusse la vorta bbona", diceva Nino Manfredi in un celebre tormentone di Canzonissima, se non ricordo male.

Comment: Giustissimo: infatti il mio “rarissimo” si riferiva appunto a proposizioni ottative come questa e imperative come «Venga qui».

Answer (score 3):

*Probabilmente arrivi prima di me.*

È corretto.

*Probabilmente arriverà prima di me.*

È corretto.

*Probabilmente sia arrivato prima di me.*

È errato.

*Probabilmente è arrivato prima di me.*

È corretto.

*Probabilmente si possano trovare soluzioni più interessanti.*

È errato.

*Probabilmente si possono trovare soluzioni più interessanti.*

È corretto.

Quindi la risposta è: Usa l'indicativo opportunamente declinato.

:)

Comment: Ma "arrivi" è congiuntivo!

Comment: @Charo No, 'arrivi' lì si deve intendere modo indicativo, tempo presente: Io arrivo, **Tu arrivi**, Egli arriva, ... Solo così si può affermare che è corretta.

Comment: Capisco. Dunque, "probabilmente lui arrivi prima di me" non sarebbe corretto.

Comment: @Charo Sì, esatto, non è corretto. Invece, p.e., 'Probabilmente lui *arriva* prima di me' lo è.

Answer (score 0):

La risposta alla tua domanda è che, nelle subordinate soggettive, è corretto sia il congiuntivo che l'indicativo. La forma col congiuntivo assegna semplicemente alla frase un tono più "alto".

La domanda ha senso, però, dal momento che la strategia (che tu citi) usata nelle scuole italiane per spiegare il congiuntivo fa acqua da tutte le parti. Io parlerei senza mezzi termini di "fantagrammatica". Se la grammatica deve spiegare come funziona la lingua, la storiella del congiuntivo come "modo del dubbio, dell'incertezza e del bla, bla, bla" semplicemente non regge. È facilissimo costruire frasi dove il congiuntivo non ci starebbe (in accordo a quella regola), ma gli italiani avvertono che, a orecchio, ci sta (pur non sapendolo giustificare ovviamente. "A orecchio" è la giustificazione).

L'uso del congiuntivo italiano è un retaggio del latino ed è legato prevalentemente alla possibilità di conferire ai propri scritti un tono più elevato qualora il registro lo richieda.

Ho scritto un articolo in proposito che dovrebbe dissipare la maggior parte dei dubbi: https://www.lavocedinewyork.com/arts/lingua-italiana/2019/10/25/il-congiuntivo-italiano-cari-studenti-stranieri-attenti-alla-fantagrammatica/