# L'espressione "mangiare di qualità" per indicare "cibi di qualità" è comune in italiano?

Tags: word-usage

Camminando per Barcellona, ho letto la scritta "mangiare di qualità" su un camion. Subito mi sono chiesta se si trattasse di un'espressione genuinamente italiana o se fosse piuttosto un calco dal catalano. Nella mia lingua (infatti dovrei dire in "una delle mie lingue"), "menjar" può essere sia l'infinito del verbo "mangiare", sia un sostantivo molto comune per indicare "cibo". Come sostantivo viene adoperato di solito nel modo che gli anglosassoni chiamano "uncountable", quindi non facciamo il plurale "menjars". Cioè, l'espressione catalana "menjar de qualitat" potrebbe essere tradotta come "cibo di qualità" o "cibi di qualità".

Poi ho scoperto che si trattava di un camion di [questa azienda](http://www.mammafiore.eu/) di Sant Boi de Llobregat, una cittadina vicina a Barcellona (sul suo sito web, tra i nomi dei prodotti scritti in italiano perlomeno stona quello del caffè scritto "cafe"). Beh... perlomeno potete vedere come i prodotti alimentari italiani godano di prestigio.

Il mio dubbio è sorto dal fatto che io conoscevo il termine italiano "mangiare" soltanto come verbo. Cercando sul [dizionario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mangiare1), però, ho scoperto che può anche essere un sostantivo e che si può dire, per esempio, "dovresti evitare i mangiari troppo pesanti" o "un mangiare raffinato". Quindi, immagino che l'espressione "mangiare di qualità" sia perfettamente naturale e comune in italiano per indicare "cibi di qualità". È così?

Comment: Direi di no, non mi sembra un’espressione comune. Inoltre mangiare nel senso di cibo ha, almeno per me, un senso informale e non  raffinato. Per cui un ristorante o un cuoco non direbbe mai “il mio mangiare è di qualità”.

Comment: Un buon esempio di uso del termine mangiare come sostantivo, da *La danza delle streghe: cunti e credenze dell'arcipelago eoliano*: “Quello, poveretto, è da mezzanotte che zappa, a quest'ora è giorno quasi, sta aggiornando, portategli il mangiare”[(1)](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=FItYBQAAQBAJ&q=%22portategli+il+mangiare%22#v=snippet&q=%22portategli%20il%20mangiare%22&f=false). "Allora si incoraggiarono fratello e sorella e con il mangiare che mia nonna gli aveva preparato, si avviarono”.

Comment: [Link](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=es&id=FItYBQAAQBAJ&q=%22con+il+mangiare+che+mia+nonna%22#v=snippet&q=%22con%20il%20mangiare%20che%20mia%20nonna%22&f=false) alla seconda citazione del commento precedente.

Comment: In italiano l'uso di mangiare sostantivato è, da quello che descrivi, simile al catalano, non si usa al plurale (la frase sui "mangiari pesanti" non è una citazione, vero? Suona davvero male). Concordo con @Gio sull'informalità dell'espressione: io leggendo su un camion "mangiare di qualità" non lo interpreterei come "cibo di qualità" ma più letteralmente come l'azione del mangiare.

Comment: @OldManofAran:  La frase sui "mangiari pesanti" provviene dal Treccani (hai il link nella domanda).

Comment: @OldManofAran: Forse, da quello che state dicendo, l'uso in italiano non è tanto simile al catalano. Il sostantivo "menjar" col significato di "cibo" l'usiamo tantissimo e non è appunto informale o poco raffinato (diciamo che viene percepito come "neutro", cioè, può essere usato in contesti sia formali che informali). La scritta "menjar de qualitat" come motto di un'azienda che distribuisce prodotti alimentari sarebbe da noi interpretata senz'altro come "cibi di qualità".

Comment: @Charo ah visto scusa, avevo fatto una ricerca sulla pagina ma essendo abbreviato non l'avevo trovato. Considera che non è un uso diffuso, da una ricerca su google sembra usato principalmente come espressione volutamente arcaica o dialettale nei siti delle trattorie (spesso anche tra virgolette).

Comment: @OldManofAran: Probabilmente l'azienda ha cercato un motto che suonasse italiano, ma che fosse capito dai catalani (anche da quelli che non sanno una parola d'italiano) senza problema.

Comment: Grazie, @Gio, hai ragione: è quello che si spiegava [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/probabilmente-indicativo-o-congiuntivo). Procedo a correggere il mio commento precedente.

Answer (score 1):

"Mangiare" come sostantivo è usato - ecco per esempio una semplice ricerca per ["il mangiare che fa bene"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22il%20mangiare%20che%20fa%20bene%22") - ma è abbastanza "rustico".

Detto questo, gli slogan pubblicitari seguono una logica propria, una ditta potrebbe sceglierlo proprio perché rustico. Ma concordo con l'OP, in questo caso trattasi probabilmente di un "catalanismo".

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @gotofritz! Una domanda: in che senso "mangiare" come sostantivo è dialettale? Cercando sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000666.jpg) vedo esempi di Boccaccio, Manzoni, D'Annunzio...

Comment: Sì, forse hai ragione, non avrei dovuto scriverlo - perché le persone da cui l'ho sentito usare sono quelle che di solito parlano in dialetto, ma le due cose non sono necessariamente collegate.

Comment: Che cosa intendi per "rustico"?

Comment: Anch'io non riesco a capire il senso di "rustico" nella tua risposta: proprio del parlare dei contadini? Non elegante o volgare? Un po' malsonante?

Comment: @DaG: Nel senso di (dalla Treccani): "primitivo, semplice ↔ elegante, raffinato" "grezzo. ↔ rifinito" "cafone, grossolano, rozzo, ruvido, zotico. ↔ elegante, fine, raffinato, signorile" ecc

Comment: "Cafone, grossolano, ecc." significa che è volgare e persino un po' malsonante?

Comment: Penso che gotofritz intenda che è un termine estremamente colloquiale (ma certamente non volgare)

Comment: @gotofritz Personalmente sono dispiaciuto che tu abbia eliminato la risposta. Io la trovo quasi perfetta (con l'eccezione che rimpiazzerei "rustico" con "colloquiale", visto che il primo termine crea confusione).

Comment: Sono arrivato alla conclusione che non ho lo stomaco per certe lunghe discussioni :-)